# app activities crashes

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

so I'm new and working on android programs  to work with activities and stuff anyways im having a problem with the class not found exception. so when i run the app i get the list of all my activities and when i select any of them none of them work, i come to the conclusion its the line with .forName which im sure im using it right .forName("package" + className)  which all classes are located in my package  and spelling is correct. but there not being located! 
here is my code all all the items in the test array are my activities

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    String tests [] = {"LifeCycleTest","SingleTouchTest","MultiTouchTest","KeyTest","AccelerometerTest","AssetsTest",
           "ExternalStorageTest","SoundPoolTest","MediaPlayerTest","FullScreenTest","RenderViewTest","ShapeTest","BitmapTest",
            "FontTest","SurfaceViewTest"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tests));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(list,view,position, id);
        String testName = tests[position];


// my problem
        try {
            Class clazz = Class
                    .forName("test.com." + testName);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, clazz);
            startActivity(intent);

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

so i added the .forName("test.com." + class) and now it just crashes here's what the lifecyle class looks like when i try to select it. iv completely run out of ideas.

```
    public class LifeCycleTest extends Activity{
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        TextView textView;

        private void log(String text){
            Log.d("LifeCycleTest",text);
            builder.append(text);
            builder.append('\n');
            textView.setText(builder.toString());

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           textView = new TextView(this);
           textView.setText(builder.toString());
           setContentView(textView);
           log("created");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            log("resumed");
        }  

        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            log("Paused");

            if(isFinishing()){
                log("finishing");
            }





    }
}
```

this is my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="fox.com"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:icon="@drawable/mrnom"
                 android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"         
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <activity android:label="Life Cycle Test"
                      android:name=".LifeCycleTest"
                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: looks to me as if there was a dot missing. Try this forName("test.com." + testName);

Answer (score 0):

`forName("package" + className)`  you miss dot.

`forName("package" + "." + className)` this may work

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, missing a dot could be problem for you.

```
Class clazz = Class
                    .forName("test.com." + testName);
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, can you post an error log?

Comment: ya i forgot to mention i tryed that too and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, <classname>.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

And make sure you include it in **manifest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name="<com.packagename.classname>"   android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
  </activity>
```

Comment: it hit me that i didnt have it in the manifest but still not working <activity android:label="Life Cycle Test"
                      android:name=".LifeCycleTest"
                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>  is what i have

Comment: @user1547386 could you please paste your stack Tracee.